# Vertical alignment in css responsive

Tags: html, css

This question might be an answered one and it may sound silly. I would like to align any element whether it is a text, image or a div to align in the center vertically and it should also work in responsive screens. I did try it by adding margin-top with manual percentages. I would like to know if there is a simple and best way to make the vertical alignment responsive.

I even did some research in google about it, some of them suggested to change the display property of the container to table and the div to table cell and then use the vertical alignment as middle. This sounds simple but it also effects the other elements in the page which I don't want to be as a table. Hence I'm looking for best alternate option. Please help. Thank you in advance :)

```css
.in-middle{
   width:100%;
   margin-top: 25%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="in-middle">
    <h1>This should be aligned in the center</h1>
    <p>Paragraph which should also be centered</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the following solution, using the [`tranform`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-property) property:

```css
.in-middle{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="in-middle">
  <h1>This should be aligned in the center</h1>
  <p>Paragraph which should also be centered</p>
</div>
```

It's not recommended to use `margin-top` instead of `tranform` to vertically center elements.

Comment: This works. Thank you. After checking your code, I got a thought that margin-top can also be used in the place of transform property. Will that be fine?

Answer (score 10):

You should use css3 [**`flexbox`**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It will center your content vertically and horizontally and it won't overlap over the content following it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.in-middle {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="in-middle">
    <h1>This should be aligned in the center</h1>
    <p>Paragraph which should also be centered</p>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will it be supported in all the browsers?

Comment: @Harish yes, IE10+ and most of the other browser support it.

Answer (score 2):

```
position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
```

this will center the element vertically.

```css
.in-middle{
   width:100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="in-middle">
    <h1>This should be aligned in the center</h1>
    <p>Paragraph which should also be centered</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

With flexbox:

```
.in-middle {
  height: 100%;      
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

<body>
   <div class="in-middle">
      <h1>This should be aligned in the center</h1>
      <p>Paragraph which should also be centered</p>
   </div>
</body>
```